# DBMS_CRYPTO Privilege issue

Tags: oracle, permissions

I am trying to grant DBMS_CRYPTO privilege to one of the user in DB and referred all the forums and Oracle help page to do that. I have followed below steps to grant privilege..

```
SQL> grant execute on SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO to ABC1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete;
```

After running the above steps, I logged into database as ABC1 and verified the privileges he own. He doesn't have DBMS_CRYPTO privilege.

Also, I ran below sql to see how many users have this privilege and surprisingly, I dont see my user in the list.

```
SQL> select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'DBMS_CRYPTO' and owner = 'SYS';

GRANTEE     OWNER TABLE_NAME   GRANTOR PRIVILEGE GRANTABLE HIERARCHY
SYSMAN      SYS   DBMS_CRYPTO   SYS    EXECUTE   NO        NO
APEX_030200 SYS   DBMS_CRYPTO   SYS    EXECUTE   NO        NO
OWBSYS      SYS   DBMS_CRYPTO   SYS    EXECUTE   YES       NO
```

My oracle version: 11.2.0.4.0, Can anyone guide me to see what I am missing in getting this privilege?

Thanks

Comment: I can think of a few reasons, but to verify that, enable SQL trace, execute the grant, and post the trace file. `alter session set tracefile_identifier='GRANT_TRACE';`, then `exec dbms_session.session_trace_enable(true, true);` and `grant execute on SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO to ABC1;`. Find the trace file named as specified above, and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you issued the grant you were not connected to the same database as when you connected as abc1.